# MySQL trying to optimize query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to optimize this query below to make it more efficient and stop loading slow. Can someone please show me what I would need to be doing to optimize this for future references.

```
SELECT * , username AS user, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pvp WHERE killer = user) AS kills, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pvp WHERE username = user) AS deaths, 
ROUND(kills / deaths, 2) AS kd FROM stats WHERE username =  "Username"
```

Comment: Add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` & `EXPLAIN` outputs, but on the first glance: are those usernames & killer fields indexed? And if so, you do know that you don't need the subqueries but you can just LEFT JOIN that pvp table _once_?

Comment: Not using asterisks is a good start -- also, I think if you get rid of COUNT(*) and replace it with something else, that should help a lot, especially if you have a giant table.

Have a look at this: 

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/

Comment: There is 1 row per kill in the pvp table. And I don't really know how to use LEFT join which is why i'm looking for someone to do this for reference for me and future people who have this issue.

Comment: Aw, come on, not even a 'best effort' on the `LEFT JOIN` part? Just that table, on killer `OR` username, and `SUM(pvp.killer=stats.username) as kills, SUM(pbp.username=stats.username) as deaths`? Anyway, I'm out the door for today ;)

Comment: anyone have anything?

Comment: Well, the `LEFT JOIN` would still work... Attempted something with it yet?